# Pip in python34 does not work properly (OS Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package, xlrd

I'm writing a data extraction from xls python script using xlrd. I'm having trouble however with pip, I just managed to get a positive reply from the cmd when i requested (I had some trouble with it at first, but a few posts helped out)

> py -m install requests

The response I now get is: "Requirement already satisfied." (with some mention of update since my pip version is 6.0.8 and there's a 7.0.1 available)

However, when I run my code part of which can be seen below I get a syntax error.

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlwt

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('editable.xls')
```

The error:

> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 1187
>       print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
>                               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your program on Ubuntu/Linux and it runs fine. 
I will recommend to follow my instructions for installing the xlrd on your Windows machine.

From [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) download the latest version of the xlrd.
Then extract the file, and using the command prompt in the new xlrd directory type:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Unfortunately I don't own a Windows machine so I can't guaranteed to you that this is the right way to install it.
The trick was that you should run the `setup.py` using the `python3` and not the `python`

(note that on my machine, I run the above command using sudo, which means in Linux administration permissions, so if you have any problems try to run your command prompt with administration permissions.)

I test this code on my Ubuntu machine:

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Untitled.xls')
```

I remove the `import xlwt` as I don't have this module, please try and let me know.

**Edit:** Also you will need the [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions) installed on your computer.

Comment: Well then this version is do support the `3.2+` so what is your python 3 version?

Comment: @user65165 hey I have edit my answer please try my new answer.

Comment: hi, it doesn't recognize python3 for some reason... I have changed the PATH.

Comment: i had tried all the steps before with python in the directory of the xlrd, instead of python3, and i keep getting the error that python can't open setup.py

Comment: @user65165 Hi, I edit my answer please check and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79367/discussion-between-user65165-and-pypiper).

Comment: YAYYY! Thank you so muchh! :)